# WPF - How to display loading message for web browser control

Tags: wpf

I have a window with 2 column grid.
Left column contains a browser control

I woould like to display a little window or something to show a 
that the webpage is still loading.

How could I do this?? Could I have a floating window in the 2nd column
that shows in front of the browser??? please explain how?

Malcolm

Thanks bendwey works like a charm.
Only thing can't find a GIF that I could use that would show something moving/revolving or the like for the overlay
any ideas where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have accomplished this is by creating a user control with exposed Show() and Hide() methods.  Below is the code.
Loading.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UK.Budgeting.XBAP.Loading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="200">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="FilledColor" A="255" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>
    <Color x:Key="UnfilledColor" A="0" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation0" FillBehavior="Stop" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation1" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation2" BeginTime="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_02" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation3" BeginTime="00:00:00.6" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_03" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation4" BeginTime="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_04" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation5" BeginTime="00:00:01.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation6" BeginTime="00:00:01.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_06" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation7" BeginTime="00:00:01.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_07" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation0}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation1}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation2}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation3}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation4}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation5}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation6}"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation7}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
  </UserControl.Triggers>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="105" Width="105">
      <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
          <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </Style>
      </Canvas.Resources>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_00" Canvas.Left="24.75" Canvas.Top="50"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_01" Canvas.Top="36" Canvas.Left="29.5"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_02" Canvas.Left="43.5" Canvas.Top="29.75"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_03" Canvas.Left="57.75" Canvas.Top="35.75"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_04" Canvas.Left="63.5" Canvas.Top="49.75" />
      <Ellipse x:Name="_05" Canvas.Left="57.75" Canvas.Top="63.5"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_06" Canvas.Left="43.75" Canvas.Top="68.75"/>
      <Ellipse x:Name="_07" Canvas.Top="63.25" Canvas.Left="30" />
      <Ellipse Stroke="{x:Null}" Width="39.5" Height="39.5" Canvas.Left="31.75" Canvas.Top="37" Fill="{x:Null}"/>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="#AAA" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Model}, Path=StatusMessage}"/>
  </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Loading.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UK.Budgeting.XBAP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Loading.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Loading : UserControl
    {
        public Loading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        public void Hide()
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

To use, make a reference in your main page:

```
<local:Loading x:Name="LoadingAnimation" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

and call from code:

```
LoadingAnimation.Show();
LoadingAnimation.Hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by displaying a "little window".  do you mean a popup window or an element that displays on top of the browser, like an overlay.  If you mean an overlay element you can use the webbrowser Navigating and LoadCompleted events to show and hide the element.

There are a number of ways to position the element it depends on the parent control.  If you're using a Grid control then just put the loading element beneath the browser control and it will show on top when its visible.

A couple things to point out when overlaying controls.  Just changing the opacity to 0 won't work, you need to set the visiblity to hidden, otherwise your events on your browser control wont fire.  Also keep in mind that if your setting a property to fade out/in using an animation that you will have to clear it out.  See [Josh Smiths post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/removing-the-value-applied-by-an-animation/).

When replying just modify your original post.  You may want to consider adding your XAML to help explain your plan.

Answer (score 0):

I found a gif creator.

The only thing is the gif does not move when the browser loads.

I guess this some threading issue.

How would you do it?

Comment: WPF has much better animation techniques than using an animated GIF.  I wouldn't use an animated GIF unless it needs to be in the browser control. you can display a vector animation on top of the browser control.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posts.

I realised of course I did not need a GIF just an WPF animation.

So I just did a rotatetransform on a Image with a gif that i found.

Works like a charm